# How do I refer to a changeset or CL from another repository in a commit message?

Tags: gerrit

I would like to refer to a changeset or CL from another repository on the same server. How do I refer to it other than copy and paste the full URL?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that a Change-Id is not necessarily unique within a Gerrit instance. It can be reused among different repositories or branches. The Commit also can be reused on different branches of the same repository.

If you want to refer to a change, it's better to use the old Change Number (like 41253) or the "full" identification: "~~".

See some information about this in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#change-id).